# How to Print the names of the sheets and the Google ID

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get print the names of all the sheets in a Google Spreadsheet in one column and their respective IDs (part of the URL) in another column. Here is my script so far

```
function getSchedule() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet_ID");
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var ids=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();
  }

  var invoicess = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var schedule = invoicess.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  schedule.getRange("A1:B").clear();
  var headers = [["Sheet Name", "ID"]];
  schedule.getRange("A1:B1").setValues(headers);
  
  for(var d = 1; d=allSheets.length;d++){
  schedule.getRange(d+1,1).setValue(allSheets[d]);}
}
```

So I believe that allSheets should be an array of all the sheet names and ids is an array of the IDs, but the last for loop that I believe should print the values of the allSheets array does not print anything. I would like to have it print starting in cell `A2`. I do not have a loop for the IDs yet. Can anyone tell me why nothing is printing in the cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

- The following line is not going to add new values to the array:
  `ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();`
- As a result, data are not added to the array and this is the reason you are not seeing data in your sheet. Instead you should use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elements (rows) to the array.
- Also since you are pasting a 2D array of values, you need to use `setValues` instead of `setValue`.
- Your code uses unnecessary lines of code. For example you use `setValues` to add the header in your file when you can simply add it to the original array in which the data is going to be appended. You don't need for loops to append values with `setValues`.
- I improved your code by removing redundant calls and made it more JavaScript friendly.

---

### Improved Solution:

```
function getSchedule() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet_ID");
  const invoicess = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const schedule = invoicess.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  const ids = [["Sheet Name", "ID"]];
  allSheets.forEach(sh=>{
  ids.push([sh.getName(),sh.getSheetId()]);                  
  });   
  schedule.getRange("A1:B").clear();
  schedule.getRange(1,1,ids.length,ids[0].length).setValues(ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();`

try this: `ids.push([allSheets[i].getName(),allSheets[i].getSheetId()])`

and use setValues(ids) at the end.